# How to add selenium test case for testing the data in the downloaded Excel and csv files

Tags: java, selenium

I have provided excel and csv download links for datagrids. How to test these excel and csv files data using selenium test.

Comment: why you need exactly selenium?

Comment: Selenium is a Browser- not a OS- RC!

Comment: i need to test the data in the excel view

Comment: What do you want to check? Whether the files are getting downloaded or not???

Comment: If its download check - http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

Comment: no he wants to control Excel... that's a misunderstanding I guess- selenium controls web browsers neither the OS nor Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At best you can check the hrefs are pointing to the correct file, i.e they are having the correct path. And assume they are downloaded when clicked. :)

Or you can follow something like [this](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/).

Or [this](http://qtp-help.blogspot.in/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html).